# make bootable usb device with programm on Assembler

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, iso, bootable

I have developed some native programs for x86 using nasm.

I want to test them on my PC's without using a virtual machines.

So I need to make a bootable usb with my programs.

What I need to do?

As I think, I must do something similar to `bootable ISO`, but how? ISO is an exact format... So maybe I need to make an ISO with my output first and then use some utillity for creating bootable images.

Am I right or not?
Maybe there is an another way, which is easiar and more clever?

Comment: find a bootable dos image, boot dos and then you can run whatever bare metal code you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You must make or get fat32 bootloader and make your image use Magic ISO to Convert that to iso.Finaly Open ISO2USB and connect usb disk and make your usb bootable.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the Following Tools

- [HP](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/42022d1260810265-ms-dos-bootable-flash-drive-create-hpflash1.zip)
- [RUFUS](http://rufus.akeo.ie/)

And use the [WIN98-DOS Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7UMjUZ0NTdBT2JFTjM5TnF5V1k/edit?usp=sharing)